# .htaccess not working on my Ubuntu 14.04 Distribution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just configured my LAMP stack on my Ubuntu 14.04 distribution and want to set `.htaccess` up to serve a website.

I followed the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file and configured a virtual host for my domain, however I am still unable to use the .htaccess file in my projects root, whenever I try to serve a page I get a `404 error`.

The `.conf` file for my domain looks like:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin alexmk92@live.co.uk
 ServerName alexsims.me
 ServerAlias www.alexsims.me
 DocumentRoot /var/www/alexsims.me

 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
 </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/alexsims.me>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
 </Directory>


 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

I tried to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` but that caused an internal 500 error even after enabling `mod_rewrite`.

Regards,
Alex.

EDIT:  `.htaccess` contents

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alexsims.me [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alexsims.me/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#--- Rewrite PHP files clean URL
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of your .htaccess file as well? And also, did you restart Apache after enabling mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes I did perform a restart - adding the htaccess contents now.

Comment: Minimal steps would be best: start with an empty .htaccess, see if you get the error; then try adding the lines one by one until the error shows up.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, I've been stuck with this for over 14 hours now, massive spanner in the works for this project :(

Comment: You forgot to tell something very important: what's in the error log? `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`

Comment: You've all been very helpful, problem has been resolved now - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Require all granted
```

in place of

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

See the [upgrade documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) for more info:

> In 2.2, access control based on client hostname, IP address, and other
>   characteristics of client requests was done using the directives
>   Order, Allow, Deny, and Satisfy.
>
> In 2.4, such access control is done in the same way as other
>   authorization checks, using the new module mod_authz_host. The old
>   access control idioms should be replaced by the new authentication
>   mechanisms, although for compatibility with old configurations, the
>   new module mod_access_compat is provided.

Comment: thanks so much - followed this through and I've came to a solution!

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue with Ubuntu 15.10.

I solved this way.

First you need to enable rewrite module:

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

and replace

`<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

With:

`<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

And finally

`sudo service apache2 reload`

Actually what is difference between `restart` and `reload` !

`restart= stop + start`

`reload = remain running + re-read configuration files.`

We have changed configuration so we need to reload configuration.

It should help someone as I have wasted 4 hours :)

Comment: Indeed was a great help. I wasted 4 more and then came across yours. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

```
AllowOverride None
```

That's your problem, right there. The 500 error you're getting could mean that your `.htaccess` file is malformed - start

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I tried amending that to `AllowOverride All` and I still get an 500 error - when I test this on my local LAMP stack the website behaves as expected, so that leads me to believe its a fault with the server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the directives you use in .htaccess are enabled.

For example if you use RewriteEngine you should have apache module rewrite enabled:

```
cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load 
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

For ExpiresActive directive you should enable apache module expires:

```
cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/expires.load 
a2enmod expires
service apache2 restart
```

etc.