# .htaccess file not working on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, url-rewriting

My .htaccess file doesn't work on my Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.
This is my file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pg=$1
```

How do i solve my problem?

Comment: This may help someone else [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675882/htaccess-not-working-on-my-ubuntu-14-04-distribution/36259341#36259341)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your information I can only guess ("doesn't work" isn't very specific).
Most probably you did not enable mod_rewrite. Type in:

`a2enmod rewrite`

and restart Apache after:

`service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 9):

First Step
Open file as

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Second Step
remove comment sign (#) if you find it before this line ( line number 187 approx.)
AccessFileName .htaccess

Third Step
Then find the line where there is

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

replace "None" with "All"

> AllowOverride All

.htaccess it's works!!

Answer (score 5):

If its Ubuntu LAMP fresh installation, you can followup with these steps. It just the sum-up from the above points:

**Step 1:**

If you have sudo access for your Ubuntu server open the apache2.conf file

```
root@etc/apache2$ vi apache2.conf
```

**Step 2:**

```
Change Directory /var/www/ from AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

share the file permission level for .htaccess from denied to granted
```

**Step 3:**

```
Change the same settings in root@etc/apache2/sites-enabled/$ vi 000-default.conf file
```

**Step 4:**

Run `a2enmod rewrite`

This step is really important. It prompts you to restart the server.

**Step 5:**
Restart the server

```
service apache2 restart
```

if the above step fails run

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it's the most comprehensive. I tried just editing the `AllowOverride None` but what was additionally needed was editing the `.htaccess` permission to granted

Answer (score 2):

If you using latest version on apache2 , you need to add the following lines in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

You need to add following inside this tag

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

after that run "service apache2 restart"